# python 3.5 nltk Stanford segmenter windows 10

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

I have setup the environment variables as instructed by the official NLTK wiki. I run into the following error in my very first example. Here are the codes:

```
from nltk.tokenize import StanfordSegmenter
datapath = "D:/Coding/stanford-segmenter/"
corporadict = datapath+"data/"
modelpath = datapath + "data/pku.gz"
dictpath = datapath + "data/dict-chris6.ser.gz"
segmenter = StanfordSegmenter(path_to_sihan_corpora_dict=corporadict,path_to_model=modelpath,path_to_dict=dictpath)
res = segmenter.segment(u"这是斯坦福中文分词器")
```

but Python gives me the following error. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:/Video data/data_processed/ugctext/test_stanford.py", line 19, in <module>
res = segmenter.segment(u"这是斯坦福中文分词器")
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\stanford_segmenter.py", line 164, in segment
return self.segment_sents([tokens])
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\stanford_segmenter.py", line 192, in segment_sents
stdout = self._execute(cmd)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\stanford_segmenter.py", line 211, in _execute
stdout, _stderr = java(cmd, classpath=self._stanford_jar, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 129, in java
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1198, in _execute_child
args = list2cmdline(args)
File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 751, in list2cmdline
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `list2cmdline(args)` in `subprocess.py` is returning `[None]`, and it is not being handled properly. I would guess that it's a problem with the `java()` call in `stanford_segmenter.py`.

From [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.html) you can see that the code was updated to require Java 8 back in 2014. If your Java version is lower than this, it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `java_class` parameter may be required.

For example:

```
segmenter = StanfordSegmenter(
    java_class='edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier',
    path_to_sihan_corpora_dict=corporadict,
    path_to_model=modelpath,
    path_to_dict=dictpath
)
```